# Equinumerous sets Examples

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

How do I show that the following sets are equinumerous or not?

I know that $[0,\infty)$ has cardinality of the continuum, but I do not understand much of the notation $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, does it mean, the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1]$.

(1)$[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $[0,\infty)$

(2)$[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ instead of $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: Nope, it is given as stated

Answer (score 1):

$A^B$ does denote the set of functions from $B$ to $A$ in set theory. This notation plays well with cardinality, because when $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then
$$
|A^B| = |A|^{|B|}
$$
Where, on the right hand side, we are exponentiating numbers.